# Firefox OS App with MVC framework

Tags: firefox, firefox-os

I am a firefox OS app newbie . I am trying to build the firefox OS app for my online shopping website. 
Can you please guide how can I start. As I read I just need a manifest.webapp file and a listing at firefox market place to make it installable.

Can anyone please suggest what should I write in launch_path? being an MVC framework I cannot put simple path like "/index.html"

Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox OS App is just a web application developed by HTML, CSS and Javascript with Web APIs, JS based devices API handling Wi-Fi, telephony etc. in smartphone. So if you can use Javascript MVC framework as like angular or backbone.js in http://jonathanmh.com/best-javascript-mvc-frameworks-2013-2014/. Also there is getting start for Ember.js from https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/02/ember-js-what-it-is-and-why-we-need-to-care-about-it/. Happy coding!

Comment: Hey Thanks Channy! for a useful pointer.. This means we cannot use php, pythons etc as backend while building these apps correct? I am a newbie in mobile app dev

Comment: @ShrutiJakhete Yes. You can make client side app without backend. If you need to store user data, you can use IndexedDB or localStorage. But, these may be synced to server database as like BaaS providers.

Comment: I thought a Firefox app could be basically a web site (built with Python/whatever), with special manifest that allows installing (and possibly more Firefox APIs available in Javascript)?

Comment: @NoBugs No. You can make offline app keeping update from web server. You can install and run HTML5 games such as Chess with offline.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example of a Firefox OS application that uses Angular & RequireJS, and thus shows how bootstrapping etc. works, please see: [ffos-list-detail](https://github.com/comoyo/ffos-list-detail).

Answer (score 0):

I think is easy to use an mvc pattern with firefox os apps, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542353/angularjs-folder-structure) maybe you will find useful the folder structures suggested there.
I would also recommend to use a framework powered by apache cordova called [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/), ionic also organize your app in a similar way as MVC pattern.

The lack of server side scripting in firefox os is not a limitation to organize your project in a MVC way, just keep in mind the pattern basis, divide your views and logic.

here an example using [angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) as your client side MVC framework that could help to organize your app in a similar way as MVC pattern:

```
your-app-folder
├── index.html
├── manifest.webapp
├── js
│   ├── controllers
│   │   └── main.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── directives
│   │   └── yourDirective.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── filters
│   │   └── yourFilter.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── services
│   │   └── yourService.js
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── libs
│   │   ├── jquery.min.js
│   │   └── angular.min.js
│   └── app.js
├── css
│   └── ...
└── views
    ├── login.html
    └── ...
```