# angular js template with routing and translate refusing to work

Tags: angularjs, translate, partials, ngroute

I am new to angular and it seems very interesting

I am creating a template for a promotional page and struggling to understand what is causing an issue on it - half of the script stopped working...

My fiddle is in here `see >`
[fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danilabelov/p0gjohg2/)

or [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/WMWuBxJipu9fWafZ2OoA?p=preview)

I have working example without route...

Can you advice me how to fix this issue please

Comment: For a BIG code example, I think using http://plnkr.co/ is easier to work with.

Comment: Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'langSwitch' is not a function, got undefined

Comment: Hi, plunker example added.
And another working example without routing here http://fiddle.jshell.net/danilabelov/EkH52/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i'd suggest you to separate your project to different files based on [best practises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542353/angularjs-folder-structure)

Secondly, 'config, controller, factory' etc are methods of angular.module object. So you need to retrieve it first like

```
angular.module('<moduleName>').config(...)
```

or use some variable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CK5R2cS7Zd9T9Kun9Epc?p=preview

Comment: thank you for explanation and for examples.

my original plan was to structure into modules but I ran into problem...