# ASP.NET MVC, AngularJS, Bower and deploying site folder structure

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, gruntjs, gulp, bower

I've read a lot of articles and questions about site folder structure (develop & deploy) and still have missunderstood about questions below.

I marked my current folder structure:

- Orange- looks like **lib** or **vendor** folder, where i'd like to    store independent components;
- Blue- folder contains my own, relative    to current project (application) files;
- Green- ready to deploy    folder, that contains minified & concated files, which used to be    included in index.html.

There are a few questions i'd like to find an answer:

- Is it correct, that the best practise is deploying to web server only **dist** folder?
- Should i concat my **bower_components** & **app** javascript files into single app.min.js file? Should i mess independent components with application files and ober ordering?
- Should i deploy **views** folder with templates **as is** into **dist/views** folder?
- Is it correct to mess all images (css images, app images, plugin images) into single **dist/images** folder?
- Is it correct to store **directive** templates in **views** folder?
- There is not relative to AngularJS **client/app/js/common/helpers.js** file,- i can't figure out where is the most obvious place for that (it could be prototypes, custom functions or objects)

I will be glad for any help, ty.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my directory structure for an angular site I'm building called [Simple Team](http://simple.team) that is bound together using Browserify.

[image]

This is my document root where my framework starts and serves public files.  All my JS and HTML is bound together into `app.min.js`.

[image]

This is how I build my directives as modules with the views `require()`'d in.

[image]

```
"use strict"

require('moment')
require('angular-ui-router')
require('angular-ui-sortable')
require('angular-gravatar')
require('angular-elastic')
require('angular-local-storage')
require('angular-moment')

require('./routes.js')
require('./modules/focusMe')
require('./modules/selectize')
require('./modules/tagData')
require('./modules/www')
require('./modules/uiSrefActiveIf')

angular
    .module('simple.team', [
        'ngFileUpload',
        'ui.router',
        'ui.sortable',
        'ui.gravatar',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'selectize',
        'angularMoment',
        'angular-loading-bar',
        'ng-showdown',
        'LocalStorageModule',
        'monospaced.elastic',
        'textAngular',

        'simple.team.uiSrefActiveIf',
        'simple.team.routes',
        'simple.team.focusMe',
        'simple.team.ngBindHtmlUnsafe',
        'simple.team.bytes',
        'simple.team.strings',
        'simple.team.auth',
        'simple.team.tagData',
        'simple.team.userData',
        'simple.team.www'
    ])
    .config(function($urlRouterProvider, cfpLoadingBarProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/projects')
        cfpLoadingBarProvider.includeSpinner = false
    })
    .controller('AppCtrl', function($state, $http, $rootScope) {
        // Controller code
    })
```

Routes and controllers

```
angular
    .module('simple.team.routes', [])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('projects', {
                url: '/projects',
                template: require('./layouts/projects.html'),
                controller: ProjectsCtrl,
                controllerAs: 'ctrl'
            })
            .state('projects.card', {
                url: '/card/?cardId',
                template: require('./layouts/card.html'),
                controller: require('./controllers/card.ctrl.js'),
                controllerAs: 'ctrl'
            })
```

Comment: Could you please provide an answer a little with `require` controllers and services in modules?

Comment: i've watched alot about browserify, but couldn't understand one thing- what's the benefits of using browserify over simple concat all in one bundle? Are there any other great stuffs in browserify that you've decided to use it?

Comment: @FSou1 I updated my answer to show you what it'd look like requiring in your modules.

Comment: Browserify is great because it's extremely easy to bring all your files together.  I did the concat thing for a long time, it is for sure better.

Comment: You separated controllers into different files and then require them in modules? A little missunderstand about separating and require controllers in modules

Comment: Sorry for these amount of questions, but i'm very interesting about your `require('card.html')`, looks like your templates shaped with module.export function?

Comment: Check this tutorial out https://egghead.io/lessons/nodejs-introduction-to-browserify-part-1 and https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-gulp-and-browserify-initial-setup. 
My templates are simple html files but my modules all use `module.export`.

Comment: Yeah, that's nice, but my setup of browserify doesn't allow to require pure html, other words, when i try to use it like `template: require('./layouts/card.html')` i got [Object object] at client side, not html markup

Comment: It could be problem of angular-route (ngRoute), i'll check this out

Comment: That's well done with `npm stringify` :) As you could notice, finally each of your html file will be wrapped in `module.exports = "<h3>html</pre>"`; thank you m8, its really helped me

Answer (score 3):

Here is my setup that I'm using for a few different enterprise Angular SPA's using bower and gulp.

My app folder is like yours, but I also keep my index.html template there. Gulp uses it and injects the CSS/JS files that I want (.min files when I do a release). I have it put an index.html in the root of the website (for debug).

I separate my bower and app scripts into lib.min.js / app.min.js. Instead of minifying the bower stuff myself, I just concat all of the .min files. I minify and concat my app scripts.

Instead of your dist folder, I stage everything for release in obj/client (VS automatically creates the obj folder for temp files). I don't include this in the solution (I don't want it in source control).

I don't have a views folder for release. Using gulp everything is stored in the Angular template cache (it's gets put in there with app.min.js). You'll see these also get a random string as a suffix (that's for cache busting).

In the end, my deployment consists only of index.html, app (dist in your case) and bin folders, and web.config. I exclude the gulpfile, bower.json, etc.

[image]

Comment: Thx for your reply, Bob. I didn't quite understand about next things: 1. why do you use obj folder and how do you include minified files in your index.html? 2. How does angular template cache works with views on deploy server. 3. Looks like you use asp.next, neither asp .net mvc and every request catched by your index.html? other requests handles with separated data project (webApi for example)?

Comment: 1 - Using [gulp-inject](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inject) to construct my debug and release index.html files. It knows where I put controllers/services etc, so they show up automatically in my index.html after I create them. 2 - I only use the template cache in my release build, works like [magic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) 3 - I'm not using Next... just a plain ASP.NET web api project. I don't have any ASP.NET mvc references (not sure why you would need them for a SPA).. I don't really understand your last question.

Comment: If i understand you right, you have separate routes to get data and get index.html and your WebApi project separate from current spa-only project. I couldn't see your `Controllers` folder, that contains your WebApi controllers with data and i'm a little confused about it

Comment: You are correct. Our Controllers are defined in another project (but referenced by this one), it does not need to be that way (just pretend the controllers project is there). We have it separate because we have 2 different websites sharing the Web API controllers.

Comment: Sounds great, Bob. Ty

Comment: Also, you asked why I'm using the obj folder. Only reasons are so that it didn't get checked in (obj is a folder for temp files). I also need the same structure for my deployment as I have for debugging... so index.html (and nested views) will reference the same path... "app/img/test.jpg" for example.

Comment: I tried to use gulp-angular-templatecache, looks nice, but you said you use it on release only?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95935/discussion-between-bob-and-fsou1).

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I not get enough time to do some research and write all answers 
May be I edit it later..

Questions 1:

- **Is it correct, that the best practise is deploying to web server only dist folder?**

Answer, Yes

Here is an example directory structure in which source code (src) is separated from temporary precompiled assets (.tmp), which are separated from the final distribution folder (dist). **The src folder contains higher level languages such as jade, typescript and scss**; the .tmp contains compiled js, css and html files; while **the dist folder contains only concatenated and minified files optimized to be served in production**.

```
.
├── .tmp
│   ├── app.css
│   ├── app.js
│   ├── header.html
│   └── index.html
├── bower_components
│   └── angular
├── dist
│   ├── app.min.css
│   ├── app.min.js
│   └── index.html
└── src
    ├── app.scss
    ├── app.ts
    ├── components
    ├── header.jade
    ├── index.html
    └── shared
```

Here is a link that you can find more information

[Gulp Best Practices You Can Use Today to Radically Improve Your Development Experience](http://blog.rangle.io/angular-gulp-bestpractices/)

Answer (score 0):

Should use folder per type: http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-app-structuring-guidelines/

Directive script and view should be in same folder.

Only deploy the `dist` folder.

Images can all be in `dist/assets/images` (or `dist/components/images`). In my projects, I have all directives, services, and images under `dist/components` (`dist/components/services`, `dist/components/partials` [for directives]). And in the root, I have a folder for each router/section (ie. `dist/login`, `dist/home`), which includes all relevant script, view, tests.

If a directive or service is used in multiple router/sections, I put it in `dist/components/...`. If it is only used in the one section, I put it right under the folder for that route instead.

Comment: Does it mean you do not concat & minify js files in dist?

Comment: I'm using requirejs/angularamd, so yes minify, but no concat.