# Angularjs and whmcs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, whmcs

I've bought a beautiful design to save time and to reduce the cost of developing a unique whmcs user interface. The design has been delivered in two formats, plain HTML/CSS/js and in angualarjs. So far so good, it is almost finished with plain HTML/CSS/js.

What I've been asking myself the last couple of days. How can I implement the file structure of angularjs with whmcs. This isn't a requirement for this project, it is more a personal thing. I tried some moving around with the pages and changing paths, but either way, I break whmcs or the design.

This is roughly the file structure at the moment

```
    app/
    ----- controllers/
    ---------- mainController.js
    ---------- otherController.js
    ----- directives/
    ---------- mainDirective.js
    ---------- otherDirective.js
    ----- services/
    ---------- userService.js
    ---------- itemService.js
    ----- js/
    ---------- bootstrap.js
    ---------- jquery.js
    ----- dashboard
    ---------- clientareahome.html
    ---------- ...
    ----- support
    ---------- viewticket.html
    ---------- ...
    ----- app.js
```

Any tips, articles,... I really don't have a clue where to look or what to learn to make this happen.

Comment: This file structure will work. I've used a slightly different structure for projects, if that answers the question.This might help a bit [link](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure) and [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542353/angularjs-folder-structure)

Comment: Due to the structure of whmcs it is not possible to maintain this structure. (I think) WHMCS uses smarty template files in /templates/themename/themefiles
and are controlled by a bunch of php files in the web root. this means I need to maintain the original structure of whmcs. What I can do is completely rewrite the structure using their api and mysql querries. This is simply to much work.