# Web app folder structure when using angularjs and node.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, directory-structure

I'm starting to learn node.js and angularjs but I'm having some trouble on how should I organize and structure the folders and its contents. Though there's already some question due this matter, I still haven't found a way that pleases me.
By now, I have the following structure:

- Client

  - controllers
  - directives
  - services
  - scripts
  - contents (img/stylesheets)
  - views
  - app.js (or should it be index.html?)
- Server

  - controllers
  - views
  - server.js

The reason I'm not using models it's because I'm doing a web service to get the data needed for the application, though I also have some questions regarding this matter. Can a web service be implemented in javascript to send and receive SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

blog post: http://www.johnpapa.net/angular-growth-structure/

Example : https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app

This question already has an answer for angularjs here:

[AngularJS Folder Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542353/angularjs-folder-structure)