# Angular 2 project without .Net framework in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular

Is it possible to, somehow, work on an Angular 2 (+ TypeScript) project without mixing .Net Framework in the project with Visual Studio 2015/2017?

I saw this question ([Is it possible to build a SPA without using .net framework in visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41260107/is-it-possible-to-build-a-spa-without-using-net-framework-in-visual-studio)), but the solution given there is to use VS Code, which is not what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer is yes.

But it depends on why you want to use visual studio for your angular2 project at the first place.

If it is only a host to run (pressing `F5` to get a running web site), you can use a `node.js` template to create a new client side application, but it will bring the nodejs server in which you won't use. But it doesn't rely on .Net at all.

From there you can create a node script which spins on your project when you hit `F5`.

On the other hand if you just need an editor `VS code` is your friend.

Comment: I like the way VS is able to give me detailed performance data (memory usage, cpu, FPS and so on...). So, how can I do it?

Comment: Performance of the client app or server side code? do you have any server side code?

Comment: Performance of the client app, which I believe is fetched via some internal Chrome methods. I don't have any server-side code. I know I can get that same data inside Chrome (dev tools), but the integration with VS seems nice and I wanted to give it a try.

Comment: In that case the Node.Js template is your friend, give it a try